# Why is Joomla 3.2 SEF working for links to menu items but not links to articles not published in a menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, sef

I have SEF, URL re-write and Add suffix all enabled and htaccess.txt renamed .htaccess. If I link to a menu item, SEF works fine. If I try to link to an article from the Content tree as opposed to the Menu tree, I get a normal, non-SEF URL.

Here's an example:

http://ritsema-lyon.com/our-attorneys.html

Click any link in the nav bar and it works great. But try clicking on one of the attorneys on that page and you'll get a completely dynamic non-SEF url, which shouldn't be happening.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How are you generating the links within your article? Do you have any third party SEF component installed?

Comment: Just standard Joomla SEF. On the attorney bio page above, I created the links via the backend editor like normal, drilling down to Content > Category > article.

Comment: Strange. Are you able to upgrade to Joomla 3.3.6? Are all other extensions up to date?

Comment: Have you hit rebuild in the menu manager? There is a dead link in the blog.

Comment: Links to menu items aren't what is giving me the problem.

Comment: I just updated to 3.3.6 and the problem persists. All other extensions are up to date and verified compatible w/ 3.3.6.

Comment: Look, for some reason Joomla sef does not update automatically when you change menu structure, you need to use the rebuild. And this can also break article links, if the articles were sometime in the past accessible thru a menu. When that happens you need to rebuild and redo the links. No idea, if that is your case, but I have learned to always try rebuild when I have issues with sef. It only takes few minutes and it works often enough to be worth it.

Comment: The articles in question were never accessible through a menu. That's the point. I'll give the re-build idea a try though, just in case.

Comment: http://ritsema-lyon.com/our-attorneys/8-our-attorneys/9-paul-d-feld or http://ritsema-lyon.com/our-attorneys/9-paul-d-feld

Comment: The point is your sef is working for the articles, it is the links themselves that contain something Joomla can't convert, my guess is that itemid at the end corresponds to a non-existent menu. The solution of creating a new menu item for the category and redoing the links should work. Alternately, you can do the same as in the example links I posted and just do the sef link manually by taking a path to **any** com_content menu and adding the article id, in example 9, after a slash. I think the readable name after the number is not used and is optional.

Answer (score 1):

It's the way Joomla's router works. Peerhaps it will change in the future, but unfortunately the only way to get SEF links on a single article is to have a 'blind' (=unpublished) menu item pointing to the article.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new (hidden) menuitem that links to a blog-layout, pointing to the category our attorneys. And voila!

The router will look up any blog menu item with that category.

Experiment with the location of this new menuitem since that will be part of the SEF.